# Grupos de 3 decimais retorna apenas 2 ao usar carectere maiúsculos

Tags: php

Galera é o seguinte to tentando codificar uma mensagem com RSA, e para isso preciso converte os caracteres para decimais e agrupá-los em 3 numa array para então fazer os cálculos. Mas estou passando pelo seguinte problema após pré codificar os caracteres para os decimais ASCII e tenta agrupá-los em grupos de 3 os caracteres maiúsculos se compostos por apenas 2 dígitos eles ficam apenas em 2 dígitos.
Segue o código a baixo:

```
<?php    
    $string = 'ThomSon';
    $valS = strlen($string);

    $code = '';
    $aCode = [];
    $valC = 0;

    $pi = 0;
    $pf = $valS - 1;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $valS; $i ++) {
        array_push($aCode, ord(substr($string, $pi, -$pf)));
        $pi ++;
        $pf --;
    }
    $code = implode('', $aCode);
    $valC = strlen($code);

    $pi = 0;
    $pf = $valC - 3;

    $loop = true;
    for ($i = 1; $loop != false; $i ++) {
        if (implode('', $aCode) == $code) {
            $loop = false;
        } else {
            $frag = substr($code, $pi, -$pf);
            array_push($aCode, $frag);
            $pi += 3;
            $pf -= 3;
        }
    }

    echo $string . '<br>';
    echo $code . "<br>";

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($aCode); $i ++) {
        echo "<br>M($i) = {" . $aCode[$i] . "}";
    }
```

Alguém sabe o que possa ser ?

Comment: relacionado (para referência): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168087/loop-infinito-ao-gerar-a-chave-publica-do-rsa

Comment: Não poderia usar openssl? Veja se ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922094/php-rsa-key-creation

Comment: Eu estou fazendo isso para estudar o algoritmo mesmo.